# Remove end part of image src

Tags: jquery, src

What I need to happen is to remove everything from `?loop` onwards from all src's. Can't just target one image.

```
1.jpg?Lo0P=f5e60563ee7227dd11b22562dc2a59678424
```

so that the src is then returned in the source code as:

```
1.jpg
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question and explain what you've already tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can split your string with `?` in two parts and you can take first part which you expected.

```
var str = "1.jpg?Lo0P=f5e60563ee7227dd11b22562dc2a59678424";
image = str.split("?")[0];
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ojzs63wv/)**

Comment: Problem it that it has to work for every image on the page, there's a load of them and can't target each individually... So it needs to be:

x.jpg?Lo0p..etc

Where x is the image name

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking to traverse and set the src attribute back onto the element without the ?xxxx bit, then you can just use the approach highlighted in the first answer by Sadikhasan within a jquery .each() (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$("img")
    .each(function(index, img){
        var $i = $(img);
        var urlWithoutQS = $i.attr("src").split("?")[0];
        $i.attr("src", urlWithoutQS);
});
```

You could also use a similar approach with .map() to gain a list of cleaned urls.

HTH

Comment: Thank you, that works like a dream :)

Comment: Excellent - make sure you mark @Sadikhasan's answer as right - I merely added a little bit of glammer to it.